# Read textfile line by line

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

[image]

I tried it this way but it doesn't find the textfile.

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    // Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
    // Close the input stream
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

All files are in the same package.

Comment: `new File("textfile.txt").getAbsolutePath()` - does that print what you expect it to?

Comment: If it's not finding the text file, make sure that the text file actually exists in the directory in which the program is running.

Comment: Try using "/textfile.txt"

Comment: And please show us your file structure

Comment: ```
FileInputStream fstream = new File("textfile.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```
like this?

Comment: It's not always obvious where eclipse will actually run your program. I prefer to store files relative to the user's home folder. `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "textfile.txt");`

Comment: @k1m0j *``` FileInputStream fstream = new File("textfile.txt").getAbsolutePath(); ``` like this?* No. `System.out.println(new File("textfile.txt").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: it prints /Users/kimoji/eclipse-workspace/Vokabelmanager/textfile.txt

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda How do I show this.

Comment: Take a screenshot of your project explorer?

Comment: okay I added the link in the post

Comment: @CardinalSystem `Error: class java.io.BufferedInputStream cannot be cast to class java.io.FileInputStream (java.io.BufferedInputStream and java.io.FileInputStream are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file is inside a the package "trainer" which is inside "src" so when you request it, you must use `"src/trainer/textfile.txt"`. The preceding `/` denotes the root of the application and is optional if you're not exporting to runnable jars for example.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src/trainer/textfile.txt");
```

Comment: ```try {
   FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/trainer/textfile.txt");
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String strLine;
   // Read File Line By Line
   while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Print the content on the console
    System.out.println(strLine);
   }
   // Close the input stream
   in.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
   System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }```

Comment: yeah, like that

Comment: yes
`Error: /trainer/textfile.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Try without the slash at the beginning? Otherwise move the file to the source folder and use "textfile.txt"

Comment: Ok, hold on, I'm trying it myself

Comment: Ok, I forgot where the working directory is, I've edited my answer